# Running pyinstaller on Ubuntu 20.04 creates file not able to run properly

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyinstaller

I'm working on a VirtualBox Machine running Ubuntu 20.04 as the software. I'm using the virtual machine to create executable scripts using `pyinstaller` that will work across several platform types.

**What Happens**

Using the terminal, I run `python3 -m PyInstaller --onefile "filename.py"`, which works as it should and creates a single file of the program. However, the name of the program is just that, the name. There is no file type associated with it and the end is just blank. For example, if the program name is `program v.1.0.py`, the executable's name is `program v.1.0`. Once I click on it, it will not run and nothing will show up. The log file I have set up shows the error `CRITICAL: Program experienced unexpected error. Program terminated with EOF when reading a line.` From my research, I understand this can happen when there is an `input` clause that is not fulfilled, which makes sense as the first line of the code begins with an input line.

**What Should Happen**

The executable should pop up a terminal dialogue as it does on my Debian and Windows devices, but instead, I get nothing, not even an indication of something going wrong. If anyone has experience with something similar and an idea of how to fix it, I would appreciate the help.